# Shortcut buttons(example: code) in Slack message box are disappeared

Tags: slack

Shortcut buttons such as "Code" and "Code block" in my Slack message box are disappeared. Is there any way to bring them back?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please click the **'Aa'** button to show formatting.

**Before :**
[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]